# Nested lists in memoir

Tags: lists, memoir, description

I am using memoir and have nested lists. The MWE below typesets, but "Hermit" starts on the same line as "Anti-thesaurus".  I would like it to start on a new line. I have tried `\\` and `\newline` and a blank line, to no avail.

If I add any text at all after `\item{Anti-thesaurus}` things are fine, but I don't have any text I want to put there.

MWE:

```
\author{Peter Flom}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[marginpar]{todo}

%% A convenience command, for typesetting the
%% word and pronunciation

\newcommand{\entry}[2]{\medskip\noindent{\Large\textbf{#1} (#2)\par}}

%\newcommand{\entry}[3]{\medskip\noindent{\Large\textbf{#1} \normalsize(#2) (#3)\par}}


\newcommand{\sclabel}[1]{\normalfont\scshape #1}

%% Less spacing around lists
\firmlists


\begin{document}


\entry{Apanthropy}{Rhymes with Ma can throw pee} %On Medium  %From Byrne
      \begin{flexlabelled}{sclabel}{0pt}{0.5em}{0.5em}{*}{\leftmargin}
      \item[Definition]
      Apanthropy is a desire to be alone or a dislike of being with others.
      \item[Etymology]
      Combines Greek \emph{apo}, meaning away or apart or without and \emph{anthropy} meaning people.
      \item[Usage] \Todo{add more, make it funny}
      ``Greta Garbo was apanthropic (at least sometimes)'' or ``while apanthropy was very dangerous when human beings lived on the savannah of Africa, modern society has found ways to  make it safe.
      \item[Anti-thesaurus] random words

      \begin{blockdescription}
      \item[Hermit] but apanthropy is the \emph{desire} to be alone rather than actually being alone.
        \item[Introvert] is different. Many introverts tolerate or even enjoy social interaction, they just need breaks from it.
        \item[Solitary] but this has nothing to do with the desire to be alone. For instance, solitary could be about solitary confinement (which pretty much no one wants) or it could be imposed by disease or disability, again against the will of the person.
      \end{blockdescription}
      \item[Frequency]
      Google Ngram viewer did find \emph{some} uses, but this is very rare, about 1 in 1.5 billion words.
   \end{flexlabelled}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `\leavevmode` should work.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.. If you want to post it as an answer, I will accept it.

How did you find this command?

Comment: I've already met similar problems, and solved it first  adding `\mbox{}`, then read things about ‘vertical mode’ in tutorial – and probably on this site. I don't think it's necessary to write an  answer, as I'm sure it already has been done.